# Replacing values in database

Tags: mysql, database

While importing my database I've realized that i made a mistake and imported some of the numbers in the format of 1k instead of 1000, and 1m instead of 1000000.

I did see this :

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn = REPLACE(YourColumn, '%', '');
```

However that would create a problem seeing how with 1.25k instead of 1250 i would get 1.25000

What would be a possible way to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` statements:

```
update yourtable
set yourcolumn = 
case when length(yourcolumn) <> 
          length(replace(yourcolumn, 'k', '')) 
then
   replace(yourcolumn, 'k', '') * 1000 
else when length(yourcolumn) <> 
          length(replace(yourcolumn, 'm', '')) 
then
   replace(yourcolumn, 'm', '') * 1000000
else
   yourcolumn 
end
```

**EDIT**: I'm assuming that yourcolumn is a character column and not numeric.

Comment: I'm getting

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when length(numbers) &lt;&gt; length(replace(numbers, 'm',' at line 7

Comment: sorry, I don't have MySql available locally. It could be you need != instead of <>, for example.

Comment: Not sure what was the problem (it originated around second else when statment) but i was able to solve the problem by just running the command two times. Many thanks